# Should electrons from the silk handkerchief align their spins when we put close a permanent magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, charge, quantum-spin, everyday-life

Should electrons from the silk handkerchief align their spins when we put close a permanent magnet? So to produce an extra magnetic field that will add up to the field of the magnet?

Comment: why a silk handkerchief? why not any other material?

Comment: The material quality you're looking for is magnetic permeability. You could probably find some experimental data on magnetic permeability of silk if you dig for a while at a university library.

Comment: @Mauricio  I think it's not a big deal to expand answers assuming the charged material is any material that is nonconductive :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft are there any electrically charged materials in this question?

Comment: @Mauricio My initial take was that it was a static-charged piece of cloth.  Perhaps that was not what was intended

Answer (score 2):

This is [paramagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism). There will be a *slight*   alignment and so a slight (hard to measure) enhancement of the field, but the effect will be small as the tendency to align  is offset by a much larger disorder effect due to temperature-induced fluctuations.